# Python sorting non logic string

Tags: python, sorting

MS Word has this default non-logic way of numbering sections with I believe has manifested it self many other places. What I talk about is

> ...
>
> 1.8.1 Ninja
>
> 1.8.2 Gaab
>
> 1.9.1 Foo
>
> 1.10.1 Baa
>
> ...

But working with strings and wishing to sort would give the following order:

`[1.10.1 Baa, 1.8.1 Ninja, 1.8.2 Gaab, 1.9.1 Foo]`

Is there any easy and beautiful python way of solving this issue?

Comment: What you need is called a "natural sort", and there are many recipes and snippets implementing it. See, for example, [this SO question and its answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 2):

You need `lambda` with **three keys** obtained from **section numbering** i.e., three integers obtained from splitting section numbering as:

```
>>> lst = ['1.10.1 Baa', '1.8.1 Ninja', '1.8.2 Gaab', '1.9.1 Foo']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x:([int(x) for x in x.split()[0].split('.')]))
['1.8.1 Ninja', '1.8.2 Gaab', '1.9.1 Foo', '1.10.1 Baa']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(section_names, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.partition(" ")[0].split("."))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Exploiting the fact that tuples are sorted in the order you want:

```
strList = ["1.8.1 Ninja",                                                        
  "1.8.2 Gaab",
  "1.9.1 Foo",
  "1.10.1 Baa"]

sorted(( (tuple(map(int, x.split('.'))), y)   # Sort according to list numbers
          for s in strList 
          for [x, y] in [s.split(' ', 1)]     # [x, y] = s.split(' ', 1)
                                              # Splits list in exactly 2 elems
      ))

# Out[43]:
# [((1, 8, 1), 'Ninja'),
# ((1, 8, 2), 'Gaab'),
# ((1, 9, 1), 'Foo'),
# ((1, 10, 1), 'Baa')]
```

Comment: Have a look at the answers from Bhat and me, you can exploit this fact without changing the elements of the `list` by using the `key` parameter of `sorted`.